# How to add a listener to a subclass of UIControl

Tags: ios, listener, uicontrol

To customize the appearance of native iOS date picker(UIDatePicker), I found a code on GitHub. (Reference: https://github.com/xiaosao6/CCDatePicker)

Now I want to add an event listener for the picker. The selected date will be updated to a UILabel.

How can I make it the way UIDatePicker does:

```
picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeChanged(ccPicker:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

```
@objc func timeChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = NumberUtils.format["time"]
        label.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }
```

Here the way I'm doing:

```
let picker = CCDatePicker.init(minDate: minDate, maxDate: maxDate)!
            picker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pickerContainer.bounds.width, height: pickerContainer.bounds.height)
            picker.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeChanged(ccPicker:)), for: .valueChanged)
pickerContainer.addSubview(picker)
```

```
@objc func timeChanged(ccPicker: CCDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = NumberUtils.format["date"]
        label.text = ccPicker.date
    }
```

However, this function `timeChanged(ccPicker: CCDatePicker)` was never called when I select a new row in the CCDatePicker instance.

How can I add the event listener for `.valueChanged`to my customized date picker?

```
//
//  CCDatePicker.swift
//  test
//
//  Created by RenYuan on 5/11/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 RenYuan. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


protocol CCDatePickerDelegate: class {
    func didSelectDate(at picker: CCDatePicker)
}

protocol CCDatePickerDataSource: class {
    func datepicker(_ picker: CCDatePicker, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    func datepicker(_ picker: CCDatePicker, intValueForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int
}


class CCDatePicker: UIControl {

    weak var delegate: CCDatePickerDelegate?
    weak var dataSource: CCDatePickerDataSource?

    let pickerDataSize = 120_000  // for loop loading

    /// 单位字符
    //    var unitName: (year: String?, month: String?, day: String?) = ("年", "月", "日")
    var unitName: (year: String?, month: String?, day: String?) = ("", "", "")

    /// 标题字体
    var titleFont  = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

    /// 标题颜色
    var titleColor = UIColor.white

    /// 中心行高
    var rowHeight: CGFloat = 45

    /// 分割线颜色
    var separatorColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet{
            setNeedsLayout()
            layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    /// 当前选择的日期
    var currentDate: Date {
        let year  = currentYearInt()
        let month = currentMonthInt()
        let day   = currentDayInt()
        let date  = Date.cc_defaultFormatter.date(from: "\(month)-\(day)-\(year)")
        return date!
    }


    fileprivate let componentCount = 3

    fileprivate var manager: CCDateManager?

    fileprivate lazy var pickerview: UIPickerView = {
        let tmpv = UIPickerView.init()
        tmpv.delegate = self
        tmpv.dataSource = self
        return tmpv
    }()

    required init?(frame: CGRect = .zero, minDate: Date, maxDate: Date) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        if minDate.compare(maxDate) == .orderedDescending {
            return nil
        }

        manager = CCDateManager.init(minDate: minDate, maxDate: maxDate)
        manager?.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = manager

        pickerview.frame = frame
        self.addSubview(pickerview)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.isEnabled = true
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder) // 暂不支持xib
    }

    override func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControl.Event) {
        super.addTarget(target, action: action, for: controlEvents)
        if controlEvents == .valueChanged {
            print("123")
            print(action.description)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: ------------------------ Public
extension CCDatePicker {

    /// 设置日期,例如`"2007-8-20"`或`"2007-11-9"`
    func setDate(_ dateString: String, animated: Bool = false) {
        guard let date = Date.cc_defaultFormatter.date(from: dateString) else { return }
        setDate(date, animated: animated)
    }

    func setDate(_ date: Date, animated: Bool = false) {
        let rowInfo = manager?.setDate(date)
        if let info = rowInfo {
            pickerview.selectRow(info.mRow, inComponent: 0, animated: animated)
            pickerview.selectRow(info.dRow, inComponent: 1, animated: animated)
            pickerview.selectRow(info.yRow, inComponent: 2, animated: animated)
            pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }
}

//MARK: ------------------------ Private
extension CCDatePicker{
    /// 分割线views
    fileprivate var separatorLines: [UIView] {
        return pickerview.subviews.filter {
            $0.bounds.height < 1.0 && $0.bounds.width == pickerview.bounds.width
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        pickerview.frame = self.bounds
        separatorLines.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = separatorColor }
    }
}

extension CCDatePicker: CCDateSelectionDelegate {

    func currentMonthInt() -> Int {
        let row = pickerview.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let attrStr = self.pickerView(pickerview, attributedTitleForRow: row, forComponent: 0)
        let value: Int = attrStr?.string.getInt() ?? 1
        return value
    }

    func currentDayInt() -> Int {
        let row = pickerview.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        let attrStr = self.pickerView(pickerview, attributedTitleForRow: row, forComponent: 1)
        let value: Int = attrStr?.string.getInt() ?? 1
        return value
    }

    func currentYearInt() -> Int {
        let row = pickerview.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)
        let attrStr = self.pickerView(pickerview, attributedTitleForRow: row, forComponent: 2)
        let value: Int = attrStr?.string.getInt() ?? 1
        return value
    }
}

extension CCDatePicker: UIPickerViewDelegate{
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        switch component {
        case 0: return pickerView.bounds.width * 0.5 * (1 - 0.45) // 根据字符宽度测得比例
        case 1: return pickerView.bounds.width * 0.5 * (1 - 0.45)
        case 2: return pickerView.bounds.width * 0.45
        default: return 0
        }
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return rowHeight
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        var ostr = ""
        let intValue = self.dataSource?.datepicker(self, intValueForRow: row, forComponent: component) ?? 1
        switch component {
        case 0: ostr = String(intValue) + (unitName.month ?? "")
        case 1: ostr = String(intValue) + (unitName.day ?? "")
        case 2: ostr = String(intValue) + (unitName.year ?? "")
        default: break
        }
        let attStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: ostr)
        attStr.addAttributes([.foregroundColor: titleColor, .font: titleFont], range: NSMakeRange(0, ostr.count))
        return attStr
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let attrText = self.pickerView(pickerView, attributedTitleForRow: row, forComponent: component)
        if let label = view as? UILabel {
            label.attributedText = attrText
            return label
        }
        let newlabel = UILabel.init()
        newlabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        newlabel.textAlignment = .center
        newlabel.attributedText = attrText
        return newlabel
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        switch component {
        case 0: // month
            let position = pickerDataSize / 2 + row % (manager?.months_available.count)!
            pickerView.selectRow(position, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

            // call the funtion to reload the days_available array accodrig to the diffrent moth
            // so that the position will fall into the right day
            if let dRow = manager?.onMonthRefreshed() {
                pickerView.reloadComponent(1)

                let day_position = dRow % (manager?.days_available.count)!
                pickerview.selectRow(day_position, inComponent: 1, animated: false)
                self.pickerView(pickerView, didSelectRow: day_position, inComponent: 1)
            }
        case 1: // day
            self.delegate?.didSelectDate(at: self)
        case 2: // year

            if let mRow = manager?.onYearRefreshed(){
                pickerView.reloadComponent(0)
                pickerview.selectRow(mRow, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
                self.pickerView(pickerView, didSelectRow: mRow, inComponent: 0)
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
}

extension CCDatePicker: UIPickerViewDataSource{
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int { return componentCount }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        let rowCount = self.dataSource?.datepicker(self, numberOfRowsInComponent: component) ?? 0
        return rowCount
    }
}

extension String {
    fileprivate func getInt() -> Int {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: self)
        scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits, into: nil)
        var number: Int = 0
        scanner.scanInt(&number)
        return number
    }
}




protocol CCDateSelectionDelegate: class {
    func currentYearInt() -> Int
    func currentMonthInt() -> Int
    func currentDayInt() -> Int
}


/// 日期数据管理类
class CCDateManager {

    fileprivate lazy var months_: [Int] = {
        var arr = [Int]()
        for i in 1...12 { arr.append(i) }
        return arr
    }()
    fileprivate lazy var days_: [Int] = {
        var arr = [Int]()
        for i in 1...31 { arr.append(i) }
        return arr
    }()


    /// 最小的日期
    fileprivate let minDate: Date
    /// 最大的日期
    fileprivate let maxDate: Date

    fileprivate var months_available   :[Int]
    fileprivate var days_available     :[Int]

    weak var delegate: CCDateSelectionDelegate?

    init(minDate: Date, maxDate: Date) {
        self.minDate = minDate
        self.maxDate = maxDate
        self.months_available = []
        self.days_available   = []
    }
}

extension CCDateManager {
    @discardableResult
    func setDate(_ date: Date) -> (yRow: Int, mRow: Int, dRow: Int)? {
        if date.compare(minDate) == .orderedAscending || date.compare(maxDate) == .orderedDescending {
            NSLog("指定日期超过了可选范围")
            return nil
        }

        let result = refreshCurrent(year: date.year, month: date.month, day: date.day)
        return result
    }

    /// 更新`年`的选择,返回新的`月`index
    func onYearRefreshed() -> Int {
        let year  = self.delegate?.currentYearInt() ?? 1
        let month = self.delegate?.currentMonthInt() ?? 1

        handleRefreshMonthsOf(year: year)

        var mRow = months_available.index(of: month) ?? 0
        if let monthLast = months_available.last, let monthFirst = months_available.first {
            if month < monthFirst {
                mRow = 0
            } else if month > monthLast {
                mRow = months_available.count - 1
            }
        }
        return mRow
    }

    /// 更新`月`的选择,返回新的`日`index
    func onMonthRefreshed() -> Int {
        let year  = self.delegate?.currentYearInt() ?? 1
        let month = self.delegate?.currentMonthInt() ?? 1
        let day   = self.delegate?.currentDayInt() ?? 1

        handleRefreshDaysOf(year: year, month: month)

        var dRow = days_available.index(of: day) ?? 0
        if let dayLast = days_available.last, let dayFirst = days_available.first {
            if day < dayFirst {
                dRow = 0
            } else if day > dayLast {
                dRow = days_available.count - 1
            }
        }
        return dRow
    }
}

extension CCDateManager {
    fileprivate func refreshCurrent(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> (yRow: Int, mRow: Int, dRow: Int) {
        handleRefreshMonthsOf(year: year)
        handleRefreshDaysOf(year: year, month: month)

        var mRow = months_available.index(of: month) ?? 0
        if let monthLast = months_available.last, let monthFirst = months_available.first {
            if month < monthFirst {
                mRow = 0
            } else if month > monthLast {
                mRow = months_available.count - 1
            }
        }

        var dRow = days_available.index(of: day) ?? 0
        if let dayLast = days_available.last, let dayFirst = days_available.first {
            if day < dayFirst {
                dRow = 0
            } else if day > dayLast {
                dRow = days_available.count - 1
            }
        }

        let yRow = year - minDate.year
        return (yRow, mRow, dRow)
    }

    /// 处理`月`范围
    fileprivate func handleRefreshMonthsOf(year: Int) {

        if (maxDate.year == minDate.year) {
            months_available = months_.filter({ $0 >= minDate.month && $0 <= maxDate.month })
        } else {
            if year == minDate.year {
                months_available = months_.filter({ $0 >= minDate.month })
            } else if year == maxDate.year {
                months_available = months_.filter({ $0 <= maxDate.month })
            } else {
                months_available = months_
            }
        }
    }
    /// 处理`日`范围
    fileprivate func handleRefreshDaysOf(year: Int, month: Int) {
        let fullDays = Date.fullDaysOf(year: year, month: month)

        if (maxDate.year == minDate.year) {
            if (maxDate.month == minDate.month){
                days_available = days_.filter({ $0 >= minDate.day && $0 <= maxDate.day })
            } else {
                if (month == minDate.month) {
                    days_available = days_.filter({ $0 >= minDate.day && $0 <= fullDays })
                } else if (month == maxDate.month) {
                    days_available = days_.filter({ $0 <= maxDate.day })
                } else {
                    days_available = days_.filter({ $0 <= fullDays })
                }
            }
        } else {
            if year == minDate.year {
                if month == minDate.month {
                    days_available = days_.filter({ $0 >= minDate.day && $0 <= fullDays })
                } else {
                    days_available = days_.filter({ $0 <= fullDays })
                }
            } else if year == maxDate.year {
                if month == maxDate.month {
                    days_available = days_.filter({ $0 <= maxDate.day })
                } else {
                    days_available = days_.filter({ $0 <= fullDays })
                }
            } else {
                days_available = days_.filter({ $0 <= fullDays })
            }
        }
    }

}

extension CCDateManager {
    fileprivate func numberOfRowsInComponent(_ component: Int) -> Int {
        switch component {
        case 0:
//            return months_available.count
            return 120_000  // for loop loading
        case 1:
//            return days_available.count
            return 120_000 // for loop loading
        case 2:
            return (maxDate.year - minDate.year) + 1
        default: return 0
        }
    }

    fileprivate func intValueForRow(row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        switch component {
        case 0:
            return months_available[row % months_available.count]
        case 1:
            return days_available[row % days_available.count ]
        case 2:
            return minDate.year + row
        default: return 1
        }
    }
}

extension CCDateManager: CCDatePickerDataSource {
    func datepicker(_ picker: CCDatePicker, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.numberOfRowsInComponent(component)
    }

    func datepicker(_ picker: CCDatePicker, intValueForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.intValueForRow(row: row, forComponent: component)
    }
}


extension Date {
    static var cc_defaultFormatter: DateFormatter {
        return self.dateFormatterWith("MM-dd-yyyy")
    }

    /// 自定义时间格式的格式化器
    fileprivate static func dateFormatterWith(_ formatString: String) -> DateFormatter {
        let threadDic = Thread.current.threadDictionary
        if let fmt = threadDic.object(forKey: formatString) as? DateFormatter {
            return fmt
        }
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = formatString
        threadDic.setObject(dateFormatter, forKey: formatString as NSCopying)
        return dateFormatter
    }

    /// 指定年月的天数
    fileprivate static func fullDaysOf(year: Int, month: Int) -> Int {
        if [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12].contains(month) { return 31 }
        if [4, 6, 9, 11].contains(month) { return 30 }
        let isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0
        return isLeapYear ? 29 : 28 // 二月
    }

    fileprivate var year: Int {
        return NSCalendar.current.component(.year, from: self)
    }
    fileprivate var month: Int {
        return NSCalendar.current.component(.month, from: self)
    }
    fileprivate var day: Int {
        return NSCalendar.current.component(.day, from: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your custom control to emit the `valueChanged` event when the user selects a row in the internal picker view.

Add the line:

```
sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
```

where ever you want your custom control to tell all registered targets that the value changed. At a minimum this would be inside your implementation of the `pickerView:didSelectRow` delegate method.

A few notes:

- There is no need for you to override `addTarget` in your custom control other than for debugging purposes.
- It's strange that you want to use `addTarget` to be notified when the value changes since your custom control provides the `CCDatePickerDelegate` delegate protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd include an example for this great question. Making `UIControl` is really the heart of all typical iOS interface programming.

Imagine we want a banner area `Banner` all across the screen and 100 high. At the top right you desire to have a small button.

Your `Banner` should "work exactly like" a UIButton in code and on storyboard.

So you'll be able to drag to an action outlet, in the completely usual way, just like a button.

[image]

Step 1, build the layout using lazy elements exactly as you do for any view layout. Put a "real" UIButton at the top right.

```
class Banner: UIControl {
    
    private lazy var trButton: UIButton = {
        
        let v = UIButton()
        
        addSubview(v)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            v.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28),
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28)
        ])

        v.setBackgroundImage .. etc etc
        
        return v
    }()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        
        _ = trButton
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Similarly, add your other labels, logos, etc. in the usual way with more lazy elements. (Or draw, or whatever.)

To make the "whole thing" `Banner` behave in storyboard and code **as if it is an "actual button"**,

it's just this:

```
class Banner: UIControl {
    
    private lazy var trButton: UIButton = {
        
        let v = UIButton() ...
        
        v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapX), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        
        return v
    }()
    
    @objc func tapX() {
        
        sendActions(for: .primaryActionTriggered)
    }
}
```

Your `Banner` will now behave exactly like a `UIButton` does in any storyboard or code. You can drag the button function to outlets, etc.

(But the "actual button area" at the top right, will be the area the user can click, and that area will behave exactly like a UIButton is expected to.)